# Posting form data of one form as nested json in a json file that has data from another file

Tags: php, arrays, json

Title of this question can be confusing. I'm clarifying it here. I've 2 forms: One for `timeline` and another one for `events`.
**`HTML code:`**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style>
  .error {color: #FF0000;}
  /* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: -75px;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}
</style>

<div id="btnDiv">
  <button id="btn">Click here to create a new time line!</button>
  <button id="btnOne">Click here to create a new Event!</button>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">X</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
          Name: <input type="text" name="name">
          <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
          <br><br>
          E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
          <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
          <br><br>
          Website: <input type="text" name="website">
          <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
          <br><br>
          Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
          <br><br>
          Gender:
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
          <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
          <br><br>
          qwe: <textarea name="qwe" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
          <br><br>
          rty: <textarea name="rty" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
          <br><br>
          abc: <textarea name="abc" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
          <br><br>
          def: <textarea name="def" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
          <br><br>
          dob: <input type="text" id="dob" name="dob">
          <br><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">  
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="myModalOne" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">X</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
          Name: <input type="text" name="name">
          <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
          <br><br>
          E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
          <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
          <br><br>
          Website: <input type="text" name="website">
          <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
          <br><br>
          Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
          <br><br>
          dob: <input type="text" id="dobOne" name="dob">
          <br><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">  
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>




<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dob" ).datepicker();
    $( "#dobOne" ).datepicker();
  });
  //modal for timeline
  // Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

//modal for events
  // Get the modal
var modalOne = document.getElementById('myModalOne');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("btnOne");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modalOne.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modalOne.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modalOne.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function alertjson(e) {
  var file = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var file_path = 
  file.open(validation-data.json, r);

}
</script>
```

**`PHP code:`**

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = $qwe = $rty = $abc = $def = $dob = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
    $website = "";
  } else {
    $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Gender is required";
  } else {
    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["qwe"])) {
    $qweErr = "Gender is required";
  } else {
    $qwe = test_input($_POST["qwe"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["rty"])) {
    $rtyErr = "Gender is required";
  } else {
    $rty = test_input($_POST["rty"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["abc"])) {
    $abcErr = "Gender is required";
  } else {
    $abc = test_input($_POST["abc"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["def"])) {
    $defErr = "Gender is required";
  } else {
    $def = test_input($_POST["def"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["dob"])) {
    $dobErr = "Gender is required";
  } else {
    $dob = test_input($_POST["dob"]);
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  // echo $data; //print data 
}

$file = dirname(__FILE__).'/validation-data.json';
$file_content = file_put_contents($file, json_encode($_REQUEST, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
//echo $file_content;
//var_dump($file_content);
?>  
<?php
  echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
  echo $name;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $email;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $website;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $comment;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $gender;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $qwe;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $rty;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $abc;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $def;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $dob;
?>
```

`PHP code` which writes form data to json is:

```
$file = dirname(__FILE__).'/validation-data.json';
$file_content = file_put_contents($file, json_encode($_REQUEST, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Whenever I submit the data of any one form, it gets written to json file successfully. This is the example json:

```
{
    "name": "asd",
    "email": "test@attendize.website",
    "website": "esdfs",
    "comment": "qasdas",
    "dob": "08\/03\/2016"
}
```

If I fill the data of another  form and submit, then old values are just replaced by new values. But I want new data to written into same json file as nested values. How can I do it?

Comment: Kinda confusing question. Can you clarify with some examples maybe? :)

Comment: Okay... Data from one form is going to a json file successfully. However if I use another form that has some other fields, then new data replaces old data in json file. I want new data to be nested into old data in json. I hope that you got me :)

Comment: Here you go. This will work but it's not perfect solution. You should upgrade code to be more reliable. Tell me if that's fine to you and if this is what you wanted (I think so).

Answer (score 2):

This should be a temporary solution because it's not perfect and it could be achieved in safer and more reliable way. This limits a little bit by how it works, so you should tweak this for better results. But in general it is working and some things were changed quite much.

- All PHP code (except with `Your Input` sentence) was mode above HTML and JS.

This will solve **Notice** errors because right now I have enabled error_reporting to show all errors and both modals are full of these notices.

- In your second modal I also put new line (just before submit line):

`<input type="hidden" value="1" name="secondModal">`

- Finally, modified PHP code (a lot, actually).

All areas that were changed are at the end of PHP code.

```
if (empty($_POST["dob"])) {
   $dobErr = "Gender is required";
} else {
   $dob = test_input($_POST["dob"]);
}
// All those ifs above

// Add all values into array
$array = array(
  'name' => $name,
  'email' => $email,
  'website' => $website,
  'comment' => $comment,
  'gender' => $gender,
  'qwe' => $qwe,
  'rty' => $rty,
  'abc' => $abc,
  'def' => $def,
  'dob' => $dob
);

// Was this the second modal?
if ($_POST['secondModal'] == 1) {
    // Get serialized values from temporary file
    $content = file_get_contents('temp_array.txt');
    $array = unserialize($content);

    // Add into already existing array new values
    $array['name2'] = $name;
    $array['email2'] = $email;
    $array['website2'] = $website;
    $array['comment2'] = $comment;
    $array['dob2'] = $dob;

    // Add newly modified array into .json file
    $file = dirname(__FILE__).'/validation-data.json';
    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));  
} else {
    // Serializing array for much easier reading when we use this later
    $results = serialize($array);
    file_put_contents('temp_array.txt', '');
    file_put_contents('temp_array.txt', $results);
}
// End of PHP code
```

The main idea here is that store serialized `$array` into temporary `.txt` file. After we fill out second Modal, we retrieve the same array by unserializing it and adding new values. Then we store into .json file.

This will result in 1 array with values from both modals.